# How to hide a HTML class for a selected item in google org chart?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I have a google org chart and here is my [source code in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w8Ytq/84/) and I have this function

```
if(collapsed == 0)
     {       
       $(function(){  
           $(".plus").hide();
        });
      }
```

I have a class named plus and it has a picture that displays for every node but I want if a node has no child item I want that class (plus image) to be hidden only for the item that has no child items. In my case it hides for all nodes and I don't need it.

In my case  person `Carol` has no children and he does not need to has plus image same with `Alice`

Thank you

Comment: You want to remove the plus sign from the nodes with 0 childs like "Alice" and "Carol"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are hiding element using a class selector, it will hide all the elements where this class is present, you should identify the node with some other selector

if you need to hide the node , then you will have to updated the data itself, here is how you can go for it.

updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w8Ytq/102/

```
var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
    // set up + sign event handlers
    var previous;
    $('#chart_div').on('click', 'div.plus', function () {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        var row;
        if (selection.length == 0) {
            row = previous;
        }
        else {
            row = selection[0].row;
            previous = row;
        }
        var collapsed = chart.getCollapsedNodes();
        var collapse = (collapsed.indexOf(row) == -1);

        chart.collapse(row, collapse);
        chart.setSelection();

        // get a new list of collapsed nodes
        collapsed = chart.getCollapsedNodes();

        // set up event listener to recollapse nodes after redraw
        var runOnce2 = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
            google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce2);
            for (var i = 0; i < collapsed.length; i++) {
                chart.collapse(collapsed[i], true);
            }

        });

      var children =chart.getChildrenIndexes(row);
      for(var i=0;i< children.length;i++)
      {
          var childrenOfChildren =     chart.getChildrenIndexes(children[i]);
          if(childrenOfChildren == "")
          {
           var col1 = data.getValue(children[i],0);
           var col2 = data.getValue(children[i],1);
           var col3 = data.getValue(children[i],2);

           data.removeRow(children[i]);
           data.insertRows(children[i], [[col1, col2, col3]]);

          }
      }

        // redraw the chart to account for the change in the sign
        chart.draw(data, options);

    });
```

Comment: any idea how to identify ?

Comment: you could have a look at jquery selectors to understand how this would work. Please look at parent, child, children, prev/next selectors. they might help

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal could you tell me with code what should I do because I don't know jQuery.

Comment: @Iamnderon provided the solution as per your requirement.

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree with that indentation on the http://jsfiddle.net/w8Ytq/100/ :)

Comment: @bigneo you solution is working perfectly but I have some images foreach node so it removes both plus and Image. Any idea how to prevent from removing image?

Comment: could you update the fiddle for a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: @Deep Yes of course here is my full project http://jsfiddle.net/w8Ytq/105/

Comment: so you want this ADL image to remain there only and just remove plus sign?

Comment: here is the fiddle if you need the ADL image to stay there and remove plus. http://jsfiddle.net/w8Ytq/106/ , hope this will help you.

Comment: @Deep on JSFIDDLE is working perfectly and this is all what i want but in my sharepoint project is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116578/discussion-between-deep-and-iamnderon).

Comment: @lamnderon, Mate this is not my solution. I just commented on the answer :P